# Extracting hours and minutes from timestamp/integer types on Zabbix PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, extract, zabbix

I have a column in my PostgreSQL database that has the INTEGER type but all it's values are TIMESTAMP type (it's from Zabbix).
I'm trying to retrieve HOURS and MINUTES from this specific column (for working hours filtering), but it's extremely slow.
My code looks like this:

```
SELECT      h.value/(1024*1024) as "Bits Received (Mbps)",
            to_timestamp(h.clock+3*3600) as clock
FROM        history_uint h
WHERE       h.itemid IN (SELECT i.itemid from items i where i.name='Interface port13 Bits Received') and extract(dow from to_timestamp(h.clock+3*3600)) between 1 and 5 and cast (to_char(to_timestamp(h.clock+3*3600),'HH24MI') as integer) between '730' and '1700'
```

I'm using the `extract(dow from to_timestamp(h.clock+3*3600)) between 1 and 5` to filter work days (Monday to Friday) and `cast (to_char(to_timestamp(h.clock+3*3600),'HH24MI') as integer) between '730' and '1700'` to filter work hours.

I believe this last filter is slowing the whole query.

Any thoughts on better ways to do this? Or to optimize this query.

Thanks to you all.

Comment: The column can't be of `integer` type and the values be of `timestamp`. I'm guessing values are integers representing the `epoch` which you then transform into a Postgres `timestamp`. Is `3*3600` an attempt add adding a time zone offset? You know `to_timestamp` will return a `timestamp with time zone` value? To help with add the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query to your question.

Comment: You would be better off turning that column into a proper `timestamp with time zone` type and doing the `to_timestamp()` on insert/update to the database.

Comment: You shouldn't mess with Zabbix database in the first place, just use the REST API to extract the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your query. In your query indexes will not work. `DB` always will be using full table scan. If you can write `explain analyze` top of your query then you can view this. The reason is this you are using functions and other operations on the fields after the `where` command. Popular DBs have a special index method for doing this. This is the function-based index (or expression index) technology. This is the first problem that decreases your query performance.
The second problem is that your query has an `IN` statement. So if the result of subquery which is in `IN` statements is too large then in many DBs your query will be run very slow. For solving this performance problem instead of `IN` you can use `inner join` statement. I write examples for `expression index` and joining tables.
Firstly we must write two functions. (functions must be immutable)

```
-- Function 1
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_week(pclock integer)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
begin
    return extract(dow from to_timestamp(pclock + 3*3600));
end;
$function$;

-- Function 2 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hh24m(pclock integer)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
begin
    return to_char(to_timestamp(pclock + 3*3600), 'HH24MI')::integer;
end;
$function$;
```

These functions we will use in creating the indexing process and in our query. Now, we can create our indexes.

```
CREATE INDEX history_uint_week_idx ON history_uint USING btree ((get_week(clock)));
CREATE INDEX history_uint_mmhh_idx ON history_uint  USING btree ((get_hh24m(clock)));
```

Let's write our query without using the 'IN' statement:

```
select  
    h.value/(1024*1024) as "Bits Received (Mbps)",
    to_timestamp(h.clock+3*3600) as clock
from history_uint h
inner join items i on i.itemid = h.itemid
WHERE 
    i.name = 'Interface port13 Bits Received' and 
    get_week(h.clock) between 1 and 5 and 
    get_hh24m(h.clock) between 730 and 1700
```